# C++ if...else statement within a function

Tags: c++

Use the max value function to print out the max value found in the grade array.

Use the min value function to print out the min value found in the grade array

Use the letter grade function to print out the grade number and the associated letter grade for each score in the array. This will require a nested if-then else statement to figure this out.

The above is what I am supposed to. But I cant seem to figure out the third part of it. anyhelp would be fantastic

Headerfile:

```
#ifndef UTILITIES_H
#define UTILITIES_H

void show_grades(int data[], int num_values);
void show_max(int data[], int num_values);
void show_min(int data[], int num_values);

#endif
```

utilities.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "utilities.h"
using namespace std;

void show_grades(int data[], int num_values) {
     for(int i = 0 i < num_values; i++)
          cout << data[i] << endl;
}

void show_max (int data[], int num_values) {
     for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++){
          if(data[0] < data[i])
             data[0] = data[i];
          cout << "Largest Element = " << data[0];

          return 0;
     }
 }

void show_min (int data[], int num_values) {
     for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++){
          if(data[0] > data[i])
             data[0] = data[i];
          cout << "Smallest Element = " << data[0];

          return 0;
     }
 }


void letter_grade (int data[], int num_values) {
     for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++){
          //// STUCK PLEASE HELP
      }
}
```

grader.cpp:

```
#include "utilities.h"
#include <iostream>

void show_grades(int data[], int num_values);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int grades[15] = {
          55, 87, 93, 77, 92, 88, 67, 81, 84, 73, 81, 92, 89, 100, 62 
    };

    show_grades(grades, 15);
 }
```

Comment: Q: Are `show_min()` and `show_max()` supposed to find the minimum/maximum values in the array? Why are they CHANGING the array?  And what happens to `grade[0]` after it's overwritten?  Q: Can you single-tep through the code under a debugger and see if it's really doing what you intend?  Q: What's the criteria for assigning a "letter" to a "grade?  Perhaps that's where the "if-then-else" comes in?

Comment: Your show_min and show_max functions are both broken for the same reason. For the grades, `if(grade > 90) { A } else if(grade > 80) { B }...`

Comment: can you tell me why my functions are broken?

Comment: @BoNicholson: Why are you functions broken? Try to debug these functions, step by step. Then you will see. And the third function *(`letter_grade`)*: I do not understand the description. I have no idea what is 'grade number' and what letter is associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Can you tell me why my functions are broken?

A: Because they don't do what you want them to do (tell you the min or max value in an array).

```
// BAD:
void show_max (int data[], int num_values) {
     for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++){
          if(data[0] < data[i])
             data[0] = data[i];
          cout << "Largest Element = " << data[0];

          return 0;
     }
 }
```

PROBLEMS:

- What do you want to do?  "Show" the maximum, or "Find" the maximum?  Or both?
- Why not simply find the maximum, and return it?  Isn't "show" better done separately, *OUTSIDE* of the function?
- Why are you overwriting `data[0]`?  Don't you want to save it?
- Why is there a `return`   ... *INSIDE* of the loop?  Do you realize that will exit the entire function without completing the loop?
- If you're comparing pairs ... do you need really need to loop `0..num_values`?
- Etc.  Etc.

Here is a possible alternative:

```
// BETTER:
int get_max (int data[], int num_values) {
    int max = data[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < num_values; i++){
        if(data[i] > max)
            max = data[i];
        cout << "Current max = " << max << endl;
    }
    return max;
}
```

STRONG SUGGESTIONS:

- Familiarize yourself with the debugger (e.g. MSVS > Debug, gdb: whatever debugger is available to you).
- Use your debugger to *ALWAYS* single-step through *ANY* new code you write ... to make sure it's actually doing what you *INTENDED* for it to do.